# Wrong Answer in Online Judge (CODECHEF)

Tags: c

I have been trying to solve the following problem on codechef
https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHMOD

I was expecting a Time Limit error but it gave me a Wrong answer. Though i found a way to solve it with time constraints but cant figure out the reason for this wrong answer.

Here is my solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int num,i;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    int arr[num];
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    int testCases,l,r;
    long int m,pro=1;
    scanf("%d",&testCases);
    while(testCases--){
        pro=1;
        scanf("%d%d%ld",&l,&r,&m);
        i=0;
        while(arr[i]!=l){
            i++;
        }
        while(arr[i]!=r){
            pro=(pro*arr[i])%m;
            i++;
        }
        pro=(pro*arr[i])%m;
        printf("%d\n",pro);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We love that you're here and this isn't the way to ask a question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please include the problem description and any code in your question.  Don't link to it.

Answer (score 0):

`while(arr[i]!=l)` and `while(arr[i]!=r)` are wrong. The indicators of the left and right sides, `Li` and `Ri`, are indices or counts, not the values in the array. You should use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i = l; i <= r; ++i)
    pro = pro * arr[i-1] % m;
```

Note that the index is `i-1` because `Li` and `Ri` are given using one-based indexing, but C uses zero-based indexing for its arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C to solve the program you must realize that the problem description assumes an array index starting at 1 instead of 0. You must therefore adjust the values of the left and right segment boundaries given as inputs. Simply subtract 1 from the left value and start the segment there. Continue processing the segment while your index is less than the right value.
Your understanding of the problem is somewhat flawed. You need to multiply **all** the values in the segment and then take the mod of the product.

See the following solution using Ada:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code Chef CHMOD
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_io;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Chmod is
   subtype Num_Items is Positive range 1..100_000;
   subtype Values is Integer range 1..100;
   type Data_Array is array(Num_Items range <>) of Values;
   Num_Elements : Num_Items;
begin
   Get(Num_Elements);
   declare
      Toy    : Data_Array(1..Num_Elements);
      Left   : Num_Items;
      Right  : Num_Items;
      Mi     : Positive;
      Games  : Num_Items;
      Result : Positive;
   begin
      for Num of Toy loop
         Get(Num);
      end loop;
      Get(Games);
      for I in 1..Games loop
         Result := 1;
         Get(Left);
         Get(Right);
         Get(Mi);
         for V in Left..Right loop
            Result := Result * Toy(V);
         end loop;
         Put(Item => Result mod Mi, Width => 1);
         New_Line;
      end loop;
   end;
end Chmod;
```